# Populate Data In mongoose not working properly?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have the two collections `user` and `userMapping` The user object is mapped into the usermapping collection with other info. I am using referencing in it.

Here is the schema which I have created:

```
    var userSchema = new userSchema({
    userId : {type : mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref : 'UserMapping'},
    firstName: { type: String, required: true},
    middleName : String,
    lastName: { type: String, required: true},
    jobTitle : String,
    signumId : { type: String, required: true},
    //userGroupId : { type: String, required: true},
    emailAddress : { type: String, required: true, unique: true},
    contactNumber : String,
    status : Boolean,
    image : String,
    createdDate : String,
    lastUpdatedData :  String,
    lastLogin: String
});
    var userModel = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

And UserMapping schema is:

```
var userMappingSchema = new userMappingSchema({
    userId: String,
    userGroupId : { type: String, required: true},
    createdDate : String,
    lastUpdatedData :  String
});

var userMappingModel = mongoose.model('UserMapping', userMappingSchema);
```

and after that I am trying to populate the data and I am getting the data only from the user collection, but not from the usermapping collection.

Code for saving in db:

```
   var userMappingWithGroup = new userMapping({
                        "userId": newUser._id,
                        "userGroupId": req.body.userGroupId
                    });

                    userMappingWithGroup.save(function(err, userGroup) {
                        if (err) {
                            res.json({
                                "message": err.message,
                                "statusCode": err.code
                            });
                        } else {
                            newUser.userId = userGroup._id
                            newUser.save(function(err) {
                                if(err){
                                    res.json({
                                        "message": err.message,
                                        "statusCode": err.code
                                    });
                                }else{
                                    customError.errCode = 113;
                                    next(customError);
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    });
```

Here I is the code for the populate:

```
   var User = require('../models/user').userModel;
    var userMapping = require('../models/userMapping').userMappingModel;

    var fetchEditUser = function(req, res) {
        console.log(req.params._id);
        User.findOne({userId: req.params._id})
            .populate('userId')
            .exec(function (err, result) {
            if(err) {
                res.json({"message":"Error On Fetching Users from DB", "errorCode":500 });
            }
            else {
                console.log(result);
                res.json({"message":"success", "errorCode":200, "data": result });
            }
        });
};
```

Can anybody help me where I am doing wrong, I am new to mongoDB.

Comment: you are populating on user model while the reference is stored in userMapping. Check it again.

Comment: I want to fetch data while fetching form user collection.Please tell me how can I do.

Comment: for that you need to add a field in the user schema as `userId: {type : mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref : 'UserMapping'}`

Comment: I did this way also, but getting the data only from User collection not from Usermapping.......I will update my code

Comment: okay update the code how you are inserting data in user and userMapping.

Comment: there is a problem while you are saving data. since you are referencing userMapping from user hence the userMapping data must be saved before user then the `_id` of the userMapping should be `userId` of user schema. Here, I noticed that you are doing circular referencing user is pointing to userMapping and in turn userMapping is poiting to user. You need to manage it carefully.

Comment: consider the thumb rule for successful population. If you have two collections A and B. A has reference of B. You should always store document in B first then the `_id` of that must be saved in A for when you will populate on collection A you will find the corresponding B's document.

Comment: can you please change the above code .....thank you for your support....

Comment: One more clarification I have, while saving in UserMapping need to save user id also........

Comment: see the answer. For your last query I have commented the code in the answer you can use that.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not totally sure what you're trying to achieve here, but your Schema and Call look wrong.

You are adding reference in the `UserMapping` schema. If you want to use that, you need to

`UserMapping.find({}).populate('userId')`

So that `UserMapping.find({})` will get all mappings and `populate('userId')` will replace the `userId` value with the object of `User`.

**Update:**
**IF you want to fetch data from `Users`** and then populate the mappings, you need to add the reference of `userMappingId` in `User` schema.

Also, in my opinion the `type` of `userId` should be `mongoose.Schema.ObjectId`

**Example**
If you want to fetch list of Articles and their authors, you will have to add `userId` reference in the `Article` schema.

`Article.find().populate("userId")`

Have a look at this:
http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html

Comment: The Usermapping collection structure is  userId and groupId, in that case also I have refrence UsermappingId in user schema.

Comment: Hi Anita. You dont need the reference on both sides. I have shown you two options. If you give reference of `UserMapping` in `User`, then you can user the `User` schema and populate `UsermappingId`.

But you have given reference of `userId` in `UserMapping`. This way, you will have to `UserMapping.find`

Comment: You will have to use the schema in which you add the reference to fetch the records.

Answer (score 0):

Update your code where you are saving data to user and userMapping. In the last else where the user is being saved, there are two part whichever you need can apply.

```
var userMappingWithGroup = new userMapping({
        "userId": "",
        "userGroupId": req.body.userGroupId
    });

    userMappingWithGroup.save(function(err, doc) {
        if (err) {
            res.json({
                "message": err.message,
                "statusCode": err.code
            });
        } else {
            // customError.errCode = 113;
            // next(customError);
            var newUser = new user(req.body);
            newUser.userId = doc._id
            newUser.save(function(err, user){
                if(err){
                    res.json({
                        "message": err.message,
                        "statusCode": err.code
                    });
                }else{

                     //////////// this  //////////////////////  
                     customError.errCode = 113;
                     next(customError);

                     ///////////// OR  ///////////////////////

                     // userMappingWithGroup.userId = user._id;
                     // userMappingWithGroup.save(function(err, res){
                     //     if (err) {
                     //         res.json({
                     //             "message": err.message,
                     //             "statusCode": err.code
                     //         });
                     //     } else {
                     //         customError.errCode = 113;
                     //         next(customError);
                     //     }
                     // })
                }
            })
        }
    });
```

Comment: One question is objectId is save to use for reference purpose.Or some other unique filed which is unique we have to use that.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, very help full for me

Comment: Mongoose only support `_id` for population. No other field, however that may be unique but doesn't count for population.

Comment: If this solves your problem do comment whether your queries are working fine.

Comment: it is working fine for me, but have to pass userGroupId instead of userId.That I dont want. I want to get the data with UserId. I think for that I have to map userId in userGroup Collection as per my understanding.Correct me If I am wrong.

Comment: clear your point more. where are you passing userGroupId? and why you don't want to pass...? I am confused.

Comment: for populate the data User.findOne({userId: req.params._id})
   .populate('userId')
   .exec(function (err, result) {
   if(err) {
    res.json({"message":"Error On Fetching Users from DB", "errorCode":500 });
   }
   else {
    console.log(result);
    res.json({"message":"success", "errorCode":200, "data": result });
   }
  });

Comment: `User.findOne({userId: req.params._id})` here `userId` is the `_id` of userMapping. do you think `req.params._id` is that value. You better do it like(perhaps/if req.params._id is _id of user document) `User.findOne({_id: req.params._id})`.